# XCode Boost C++ Library compiling error

Tags: xcode, c++11, boost

I've post this issue 3weeks ago,
And I now post it again.
I use 3rd party library in my project.
Boost C++ Library.
only circular_buffer.hpp header file make trouble.
I don't know what means error message.
so, I post error logs today.

===================environment
My mac os 10.11 version
Xcode version 7.1.1(7B1005)

C++ Language Dialect : c++11[-std=c++11]
C++ Standard Library : libc++(LLVM C++ standard library with C++11 support)

====================error logs

/Users/genosyde/Downloads/Coding/ofFrameWork/of_v0.9.4_osx_release/addons/ofxOSXBoost-master/libs/boost/include/boost/circular_buffer.hpp:39:27: No member named 'remove_pointer' in namespace 'boost::move_detail'
/Users/genosyde/Downloads/Coding/ofFrameWork/of_v0.9.4_osx_release/addons/ofxOSXBoost-master/libs/boost/include/boost/circular_buffer.hpp:40:27: No member named 'add_pointer' in namespace 'boost::move_detail'
/Users/genosyde/Downloads/Coding/ofFrameWork/of_v0.9.4_osx_release/addons/ofxOSXBoost-master/libs/boost/include/boost/circular_buffer.hpp:45:7: No member named 'disable_if_c' in namespace 'boost::move_detail'; did you mean '::boost::disable_if_c'?
/Users/genosyde/Downloads/Coding/ofFrameWork/of_v0.9.4_osx_release/addons/ofxOSXBoost-master/libs/boost/include/boost/circular_buffer.hpp:50:27: No member named 'is_const' in namespace 'boost::move_detail'

there are hundred of errors below.
thanks for reading and have a good day!!!

Comment: could you give link to the circular_buffer.hpp? check if remove_pointer's  declaration is not being disabled because of the any #ifdef macros.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your interest.
I'm sorry
But, I don't understand your request. 
circular_buffer.hpp is 3rt_party library from boost.org.
Any time, you can download it for individual OS.
And I send you a link, that is my test project file link in google drive.
If you download it, you might just run it.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4J46iW2HRnoYmNhcVB2OXhkX1U

my test of xcode porject's location:
of_v0.9.4_osx_release/addons/ofDelayLine/BoostTest/boostTest.xcodeproj
If you got Xcode, just double click it on finder.

I just add circular_buffer.hpp on ofApp.h to use it.